# Eclipse refuses to create a new Java class

Tags: eclipse

Somehow I got my Eclipse project into a bad state. How can I fix it?

I tried to rename a .java file from "MyClassName.java" to "MyclassName.java" and the file disappeared from the project UI. Now, when I try to create a new class called "MyclassName" using File->New->Class, Eclipse doesn't create the class. Instead, in the source directory, it creates a file called "MyClassName (Case Conflict).java".

Comment: Hit refresh.  You're on Windows, right?

Comment: No, on linux (crunchbang). Hitting refresh was the first thing I tried.

Comment: First I tried this idea to recover a corrupt workspace, but that didn't solve the problem: http://letsgetdugg.com/2009/04/19/recovering-a-corrupt-eclipse-workspace/

Comment: This seemed to work, but I have no idea *why*. I created a new class called "MyClassName.java" and this succeeded. Then I deleted that class from the project (right-click -> delete, in the project explorer). Then I recreated the class with the adjusted capitalization, and it seems to have succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and for me it turned out it was not an Eclipse issue but a Dropbox issue.  The source code folder was synced on Dropbox, and Dropbox kept "solving" the naming conflict of the Java files.  Solution was just to open the Dropbox web page and delete all of the files from Dropbox.